# Saving compilation time by saving parts of the result and accessing it

Tags: python, time, compilation, nlp

So I'm using the spacy library (NLP), to assign certain attributes to data. But it's a lot of data (100,000+ questions and answers). It takes about a minute to assign attributes to all the data.

I was wondering if I could save the data with the given attributes somewhere, and next time I compile it doesn't need to spend all the time reattributing them but rather it can look for the data with the given attributes that is saved somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the expected result in a file and load it the next time you need it. The best way to do that is using pickle module.

Documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html

Examples:
https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle